# Asp.net intelligencia UrlRewriter with 2 querystring parameter (hiding one of them)

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I'am using intelligencia.UrlRewriter on my web site.

I'am sending two querystring parameter to profil page.

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkProfil" runat="server"   Text='profil' NavigateUrl='/u/9f51e845-1089-4495-bd66-964db5b9c47b/tiju' ForeColor="Silver"></asp:HyperLink>
```

web config :

```
<rewrite url="~/u/(.+)/(.+)" to="~/Profil.aspx?user_id=$1&amp;user_name=$2" />
```

and url seems like

http://yxyx.com/u/9f51e845-1089-4495-bd66-964db5b9c47b/tiju

But I want to make like

http://yxyx.com/u/tiju
or directly
http://yxyx.com/tiju (like facebook & twitter)

How can I hide user id parameter on url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have http://yxyx.com/u/tiju you should set it in the HyperLink

```
<asp:HyperLink ... NavigateUrl='/u/tiju' ...
```

In this case rewrite rule could be as

```
<rewrite url="~/u/(.+)" to="~/Profil.aspx?user_name=$1" />
```

As you see, in this case you will send only one parameter (tiju)

Comment: Thanks.But I have to use user id parameter on querystring.I need both of them to select user profil

Comment: You can't hide parameter and then use it. The idea of rewriting is to change format but not the content. So, if id is required, it must be in the url. I think you have a problem there - you have 1 user but send 2 parameters (id and name). You should not send both of them - either 1) send id and get name by id, 2) or send name and get id by name. Since you want to have http://yxyx.com/u/tiju - you most likely do not need to send id.

Comment: Much thanks @smirnov you are right.I will send just username parameter and I will get id in sql query.Thanks again :) Maybe you can change your answer.And I will mark it.